# Create an apt-cache on host for multiple vagrant installations

Tags: vagrant

When you startup a vagrant box using a bootstrap.sh, you have to download all packages with apt-get inside each box again.

How can I set up an external folder on my host, that is used for all boxes as cache?

Maybe somehow adding the apt-cache folder in the `Vagrantfile` lilke this?

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/var/cache/apt/archives/", "/var/cache/apt/archives/"
```

Comment: sounds good - did you try this approach ? you faced any issues ?

Comment: I just tried this, but I get an error, that I cannot access the `/var/cache/apt/archives/lock` file, no matter what permissions I gave it on the host But it seems to work, if I create an empty folder  `/var/tmp/vagrant-apt-cache` and use that one. the first time it runs fine now, filling this external folder

Comment: Maybe that solution already works, if you use nfs: `, type: "nfs"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mount the same folder as on your host mashine, but you can create a special folder for your vagrant boxes.

Add these lines in my `Vagrantfile`:

```
  # add the host apt cache so packages don't have to be downloaded each time
  # you need to create this before you start vagrant up:
  #sudo mkdir -p /var/tmp/vagrant/apt-archives/
  #sudo mkdir -p /var/tmp/vagrant/apt-lists/
  #sudo chmod 777 /var/tmp/vagrant/apt-archives/ /var/tmp/vagrant/apt-lists/
  config.vm.synced_folder "/var/tmp/vagrant/apt-archives/", "/var/cache/apt/archives/", type: "nfs"
  config.vm.synced_folder "/var/tmp/vagrant/apt-lists/", "/var/lib/apt/lists", type: "nfs"
```

you must create those folders before the first run of `vagrant up` yourself. Then everything works fine without having to download anything you already have again.

*Note:* I am not sure, but it could be, that this gets conflicts, if you use different distributions in different vagrant mashines